# rsync and compression for local network

Tags: rsync, readynas

I'm in the process of backing up my ReadyNAS NV to a linux server with rsync. Is the -z or --compress option worthwhile over a local network? Or am I just adding overhead on the ReadyNAS when I don't care about saving bandwidth? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get argument about this, but...

I wouldn't bother on a local network. Compression just burns up your CPU and probably won't save you enough time on the backup to justify it, since the network link is probably faster than you can push data through it, compressed or not.

Now if you were running rsync across a WAN then it would be a good idea; since the network link is much slower you would save a lot of time.